# NIC says UP but not able to ping

Tags: networking, rhel, drivers

Had to replace an NIC in my server and I cannot get it to go active.

Running RHEL 7 and the device is an AT-2911SX/LC-901. I've done the following:

- Deleted the rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d`
- Changed the HWADDR in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-p1p1`
- Issued `reboot` command
- Issued `ifconfig -a` to see that `p1p1` was up with an IP (which it wasnt before)
- Issued `ping 192.168.0.42` which is a box on the same rack connected to the switch; fails
- Issued `ethtool -i p1p1` to see the driver information which was `tg3`

There are no lights from the rear of the case on the slot where the NIC is. The box at `192.168.0.42` is an identical box but its `p1p1` is running `bnx2x`, not sure if thats the issue.

Any ideas for troubleshooting what else could case it to not ping or connect? The switch it is connected to also shows that it is not TX/RX.

**Updates:**

Running `dmesg | egrep -i -e tg3 -e p1p1` I get the following:

- IPv6 ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP) p1p1: link is not ready
- irq 255 - 275 is MSI/MSI-X
- eth4 renamed p1p1

Unforunately I cannot directly post output here due to system security. There are also lines for `eth0`, `em1` through `em3` and that all have a section like so:

- WiredSpeed[1], EEE[1], ASF[1]

However the same line for `eth4` which becomes `p1p1`, those values are `[0]`.

Comment: How did it get the IP, and which IP was it? Possibly a 169.. IP? Also do `ip route get 192.168.0.42` to see if the routing table is correct, and `tcpdump -ni p1p1` to see if you get any traffic at all (at least broadcasts should show up).

Comment: @dirkt `tcmpdump` does nothing on `192.168.0.42` but traffic returns if run on the machine at `192.168.0.42`. The IP was set up prior by somebody who did no documentation I am afraid.

Comment: @dirkt The IP is listed in the `ifcfg-p1p1` file. Forgot to mention `ip route get ...` returns the a single line that says `cache`. A `netstat -rn` shows in routing table.

Answer (score 2):

UP is the *administrative state* indicator, or what you have configured the NIC to do. The corresponding *operational state* indicator, or what the NIC has actually been able to do, would be RUNNING.

If you see `UP` but not `RUNNING` in the `ifconfig -a` output, it usually means the NIC is not detecting a link from the cable, i.e. the cable is not properly plugged in or is broken.

Since you are talking about a fiberoptic NIC, there is one more thing you should check: if you have connected the NIC's TX to the switch's TX and respectively for RX, then the TX fibre has transmitters in both ends trying to push light into the fibre and no receivers, and the RX fibre is completely dark because it has only receivers connected to it at both ends. The optic cables should always be connected so that the TX at one side ends up to RX at the other side and vice versa.

Since the card is a SX (short-haul) variant, the wavelength of the light used is 850 nm, or a very deep red. With the NIC in the UP state and the cable disconnected, you should see a dim red glow from the TX-side connector.

**However**, avoid looking directly into the connector with unprotected eyes: that is a bad habit that might cost you your eyesight if you ever accidentally look into a LX (long-haul) fiberoptic. They use 1310 nm laser transmitter, which is infrared (=invisible), and has enough power that it can burn new blind spots into your retinas if it hits them. If you don't have an appropriate tool for detecting the optical signal, give the connector some shade and try to see the reflection of the SX-type light on your hand, a piece of paper, or any non-shiny surface. It's easiest to see at the female connector, but the male end of a connected cable can also produce a tiny faint spot of red light.

If you can't get it working by switching the halves of the pair of fiberoptic cables around, check the optic cables carefully. A kinked fiberoptic cable can easily be fatally damaged. Test with a new cable if you're unsure.

---

The `tg3` driver needs a firmware file - does `/lib/firmware/tigon/tg3.bin` exist?

If not, get the `linux-firmware-20190429-72.gitddde598.el7.noarch.rpm` file (or similar) from RHEL installation media or download it directly from RedHat using `yum --downloadonly --downloaddir=. linux-firmware` in the other RHEL7 system. Copy it to USB stick or some other removable media, move it to the system that has the problem NIC and install with `yum localinstall <pathname_of_the_RPM_file>`. Then reboot (or disable the network interface, unload & reload the `tg3` module and re-enable) to see if it works better now.

If you run `dmesg | grep -i -e tg3 -e p1p1`, is there any output?

Of course, it is possible that your replacement NIC was bad (Dead On Arrival) and needs to be replaced again.

Comment: NIC shows `<UP, BROADCAST, MULTICAST>` and not `RUNNING`. Swapped cables with another running NIC and worked that continued to run fine. Verified TX to RX and still no result.

Comment: @datta I just noticed the NIC needs a firmware file - see updated answer.

Comment: The `tg3.bin` does exist, any special commands I should run with it?

Comment: Not really; the `tg3` module should load it automatically after the module is loaded and the NIC is being activated. If there is a problem with the firmware loading, there should be a message in `dmesg` output saying so.

Comment: Okay. The server is rebooting right now but I will run it afterwards. I don't work much with Linux systems so I'm learning as we go right now. I should just execute the firmware from the terminal and then reboot when its done? What is `dmesg`? Do I need to issue that command?

Comment: `dmesg` is a command that displays messages from the kernel message buffer. It usually contains a lot of informational/diagnostic messages, but if the kernel or some kernel module has a problem of some sort, the most descriptive error messages from them can usually be found in the `dmesg` output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100372/discussion-between-datta-and-telcom).

Comment: Of note, I ran `ifdown p1p1` and it disconnected successfully, but `ifup p1p1` returns a Connection Activation Failure and says `p1p1` is not available at this time.

Comment: Using `nmtui` I can activate and deactive `p1p1` on `eth4` without issue